# File uploading with KnockoutJS and ASP .Net MVVM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Does anyone have experience with ASP .Net MVVM and Knockout JS. In my application, I need to allow users to upload files. I find it difficult to find examples or any documentation online that will help me with this problem. Can someone please direct me with some tips regarding this problem?

BTW, I do not need anything fancy, just a simple input=file button that will allow me to upload a single file. Later the file will need to be processed from a server side script.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7c6j/1/). It doesn't physically upload the files to the server. However, it uses a custom KO binding handler to track the files selected on the file input control in the ViewModel.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.files = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    valueAccessor()(element.files);
    $(element).on("change", function() {
      valueAccessor()(element.files);
    });
  }
};
```